# OpenGLES how to make a 3D object iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, objective-c, opengl-es2

I am a newbie in OpenGLES, so pardon me if I cannot state the question properly.

1. Is it possible to create a 3D box with the following imports only:
   OpenGLES, QuartzCore, GLKit
2. I have created a 2D object, (squares, triangles, polygons) but I want to make them into 3D without using cocos3D or blender or other frameworks or api (if its possibe). But how?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a 2D object is the same as creating a 3D object. You just need more vertices you would go from 4 vertices in a square to 8 to create a cube. Also, the same happens to indices, vertex color and normals.

If you want to properly set up a 3D shape (a cube) with proper texture, you need to calculate the texture coordinates. The reason you don't do this yourself is because is inefficient. You need to use blender to get the proper coordinates for vertices, normals, colors and textures.

Using blender usually takes about 20 seconds to create a cube with textures or to create a 3D human character. If you do the first manually it would take you about two days to complete. More over, if you do a 3D human character manually it might result impossible due to the number of coordinates multiplied by 4 because of the vertices/normals/color/texture.

My suggestion is to use blender, you should watch a youtube tutorial. Then you would be ready to go in less that 30 minutes.

Comment: Hello Pixelapp, will do your suggestion about using blender. thank you for your reply. :)